# NSString encoding conversion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

i have a problem with this particular NSString B and Ｂ . As you can see the encoding is different. So I am wondering if there is any way to convert Ｂ to B so that the computer can standardize the character.

Comment: How did the character get into the string - if from a file how was it read?

Comment: Note that the first character is an ASCII B and the second character is Unicode code point FF22.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
NSString *newString = [oldString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Ｂ" withString: @"B"];
```

Comment: Yeah but I want to do this for a more general case. Right now I use isEqualToString to its corresponding string such as B isEqualToString Ｂ  which is lame and iterative. So I wonder if there is any method to change the unicode to its ascii